# how to show image loading gif using jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, image, load

Can any one suggest how to do show image loading gif when image is loading in run-time using jQuery.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

As an additional option to the article posted, you could bind to the ajax function (if you are using ajax). Here is an example of how I do this in my apps (it works great).

```
function AddAjaxLoader(DivObject, Message) {
if (Message === undefined || Message === "") { Message = "Loading..."; }
var loader = $("<span />", {
    'class': 'ajaxLoading',
    html: '<span class="ajaxLoadingIcon">&nbsp;</span><span>' + Message + '</span>'
});

$(DivObject).hide().after(loader);

loader.ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $(DivObject).show();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
}
```

and the CSS:

```
.ajaxLoadingIcon
{
    padding:9px;
    background: url(../Images/Icons/16_ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Or without ajax...

```
function AddLoader(DivId) {
    $("#" + DivId).html('<div class="ajaxBlock"><span class="ajaxLoadingIcon">&nbsp;</span> Loading...</div>');
}
```

Comment: sorry brother i dont no ajax u know any method using javascript or jquery

Comment: No problem, you will just have to set and remove the loader manually.  See edited answer.